# If $y_n=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^{-nt}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t $ then where does $y_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $\displaystyle y_n=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^{-nt}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t $, then where does $y_n$ converges?

**Try**

$$|y_n - y_m|\leq \int_{1}^{2} \frac{|e^{-nt-mt}|}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \leq \ln 2, $$

which doesn't tend to $0$ as $n$ tend to $\infty$ hence $y_n$ is not convergent and also it is not divergent to $\infty$.
Am I correct. Please help me learn if there is any other way to solve these kind of problems!

Comment: Your bound is too crude. As a hint, note that $e^{-nt}\leq e^{-n}$ if $t \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks @Sangchul Lee. As you said $|y_n|=|\int_{1}^{2} \frac {e^{-nt}} t dt |\leq \int_{1}^{2} | \frac {e^{-nt} } t| dt \leq \int_{1}^{2} \frac {e^{-n}} t dt =\frac {\ln 2}{e^n} $ which tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Hence the sequence converges to $0$. Am I correct now!

Comment: $e^{ - nt}  - e^{ - mt}  \ne e^{ - nt - mt} $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y_n \rightarrow 0$ because $$0 \leq y_n \leq e^{-n}.$$ The right hand side inequality above is true because $e^{-nt}/t \leq e^{-n}$ for each $t \in [1, 2]$.

Comment: The question says nothing about $t$. Now if $0<t<1$ then $\frac 1t$ becomes unbounded as $t$ tends to $0$ hence in that case $y_n$ becomes unbounded isn't it?

Comment: The integral is over $t \in [1, 2]$ (is that right?) which would mean that $t$ lies between 1 and 2.

Comment: Ah! Sorry. You are right